# Types of Property 'Providers' are incompatible

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement MSAL 2.0 and the configurations are reading from JSON. So did a module and here is the class

```
export class MsalApplicationModule {
    
    static forRoot() {

        return {
            ngModule: MsalApplicationModule,
            providers: [
                ConfigService,
                { provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN },
                { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializerFactory, multi: true },                     
                     {
                       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                       useClass: MsalInterceptor,
                       multi: true
                     },
                     {
                       provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
                       useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
                     },
                     {
                       provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
                       useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
                     },
                     {
                       provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
                       useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
                     },
                     MsalService,
                     MsalGuard,
                     MsalBroadcastService                     

            ]
        };
    }
}
```

But when I use this class in app module imports like this

```
MsalApplicationModule.forRoot()
```

It gives an error

> Error: src/app/app.module.ts:62:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ ngModule:
> typeof MsalApplicationModule; providers: (typeof MsalService | typeof
> MsalBroadcastService | typeof MsalGuard | typeof ConfigService | ... 5
> more ... | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'any[] |
> Type | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.   Type '{ ngModule: typeof
> MsalApplicationModule; providers: (typeof MsalService | typeof
> MsalBroadcastService | typeof MsalGuard | typeof ConfigService | ... 5
> more ... | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to type
> 'ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
> Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
> Type '(typeof MsalService | typeof MsalBroadcastService | typeof MsalGuard | typeof ConfigService | { provide: InjectionToken;
> useFactory?: undefined; multi?: undefined; useClass?: undefined; } |
> ... 4 more ... | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
> Type 'typeof MsalService | typeof MsalBroadcastService | typeof MsalGuard | typeof ConfigService | { provide:
> InjectionToken; useFactory?: undefined; multi?: undefined;
> useClass?: undefined; } | ... 4 more ... | { ...; }' is not assignable
> to type 'Provider'.
> Type '{ provide: InjectionToken; useFactory?: undefined; multi?: undefined; useClass?: undefined; }' is not
> assignable to type 'Provider'.
> Type '{ provide: InjectionToken; useFactory?: undefined; multi?: undefined; useClass?: undefined; }' is not
> assignable to type 'FactoryProvider'.
> Types of property 'useFactory' are incompatible.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Function'.
>
> 62     MsalApplicationModule.forRoot()

I didnt understand what I did wrong. Only the error shows in that import part in appmodule. Nowhere else. I have copied the msalapplicationmodule from my old Angular 9 project. Current one is Angular 11 with MSAL 2.0

Comment: I haven't looked into this much, but aren't you missing `use*` in the second line of `providers`: `{ provide: AUTH_CONFIG_URL_TOKEN },`?